# Stay longer than grace period on a J-1 Visa

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, visa-extensions, j1-visas

I am currently on exchange under a J-1 Visa. I know I can stay another 30 days longer after my Visa expires, however I intend to travel around the USA and stay for 45 days after my visa expires. What are my options for extending my stay? Do I need to register for the VWP?

Comment: Do you have the two year home residence requirement?

Comment: No, I cannot become permanent residents in the U.S, change status in the U.S., or get work or family-based visa status.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Comment: US visas are solely for entry and the visa's expiration date has nothing to do with how long you can stay. You can stay for 30 days after the completion of your J-1 program, as given on your DS-2019. Are you saying that you want to stay for 45 days after the end of your J-1 program?

Comment: To confirm, your J-1 visa and/or DS-2019 says that you are subject to the INA 212(e) two-year home residency requirement, correct?

Comment: Correct, I want to stay for longer than allowed according to the grace period, so I want to stay for 45 days after the end of my J-1 program. Also, I am not subject to the two-year home residency requirement.